# Multiple Bots per FB app

Tags: facebook, postback, bots, messenger

I am running into a problem with FB messenger bot. Here is what is happening:
I have one app ( I want to use the same APP_SECRET)
I have two pages with different names
I have two different bots - one per page
I have one server / webhook

When I send messages to each of them, they work fine. I am using Generic template for both - with buttons.

When I select any button on the first bot, it works -  gets post back event
When I select  any button the second bot, webhook doesn't even gets called
If I swap the bots (first with second), I see the same behavior, new first bot gets post back events and the new second doesn't.

Any idea if this is a problem with FB Messenger framework? Or any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the snippet in which you handle the postback events?
I think I can help since I've managed to run 5 bots on the same webhook.